# Telnetlib read methods do not output the stdout from the router terminal

Tags: cisco, telnetlib

The code:

[image]

but the output from the cisco router:

[image]

although directly in the router's console:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The cisco devnet always-on devices have been used for this purpose. And this is also the reason of the unexpected behaviour. The solution is rather to reserve your own sandbox devices, so that you have a full control of the configuration.